# Solving with only loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The number 124 has the property that it is the smallest number whose first three multiples contain the digit 2. Observe that 
124*1 = 124, 124*2 = 248, 124*3 = 372 and that 124, 248 and 372 each contain the digit 2. It is possible to generalize this property to be the smallest number whose first n multiples each contain the digit 2. Write a function named smallest(n) that returns the smallest number whose first n multiples contain the digit 2. Hint: use modulo base 10 arithmetic to examine digits.

Its signature is
int smallest(int n)

Examples
If n is return  because
4   624 because the first four multiples of 624 are 624, 1248, 1872, 2496 and they all contain the 
digit 2. Furthermore 624 is the smallest number whose first four multiples contain the digit 2. 
5   624 because the first five multiples of 624 are 624, 1248, 1872, 2496, 3120. Note that 624 is also 
the smallest number whose first 4 multiples contain the digit 2. 
6   642 because the first five multiples of 642 are 642, 1284, 1926, 2568, 3210, 3852 
7   4062    because the first five multiples of 4062 are 4062, 8124, 12186, 16248, 20310, 24372, 28434. 
Note that it is okay for one of the multiples to contain the digit 2 more than once (e.g., 24372).

I tried to solve this by this way

```
//Its a incomplete code    
public static int smallest(int n)
            {
                int i = 1;
                for (; ; )
                {
                    int temp = 0;
                    int myNum = 0;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    {
                        myNum = i * j;
                        //check for condition
                    }
                    //if condition ture break
                }
            }
```

But I am stick to the problem is I cannot create hard coded n times variable.. Can you help me proceed that?

You may assume that such a number is computable on a 32 bit machine, i.e, you do not have to detect integer overflow in your answer.

Comment: You have an infinite loop without an exit condition.

Comment: Can anyone please provide me the hint?? I am not asking for the solution. Just a hint how to do?

Comment: Its incomplete code.. I was doing it.. Ron Beyer. But I dont know how to compare with n times.. I mean can u give me a hint

Comment: Just add a variable, say firstContain, everytime you verify the number contain the digit 2, increment it, if it fail, just skip to the next number and reset firstContain, if the firstContain equal to n, return the number

Comment: Try Searching for "For loop", your for loop syntax is very interesting..

Comment: Thank you Martheen it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static int smallest(int n)
    {
        int i = 1;
        for (; ; )
        {
            int contain = 0;
            int temp = 0;
            int myNum = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                myNum = i * j;
                temp = myNum;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (temp % 10 == 2)
                    {
                        contain++;
                        break;
                    }

                    temp = temp / 10;
                    if (temp <= 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (contain == n)
                break;
            i++;

        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace firstconsoleproject
{
 class MainClass
 {
  public static void Main (string[] args)    
  {
   int first=4;
   int c=0;
   int ax;
   int ai;
   Console.WriteLine ("please enter n");
   ax = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
   for (int i=11 ; ax>0 ;)
   {   if (first==1) 
    {
     c = ax+1;
     i++;
    } 
    c--;
    ai=i*c;
     for (int ten=10 ;  ; )
    { 
          if(ai%ten==2)
          {
      first=0; 
      break;          
          }else if (ai==0)
         {
      first=1;
      break; 
      }
          ai/=10;
       
    }
    
    if (c==0){Console.WriteLine("number is "+i);break;}
   
       }Console.ReadKey ();

    
       }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function smallest n
 public int smallest(int a)
        {
            int temp = 0, holder = 0, k = 0;
            if (a <= 0) return 0;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 100; i < Int16.MaxValue; i++)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    k = 0;
                    int[] array = new int[a];
                    for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++)
                    {
                        holder = i * j;
                        temp = holder;
                        while (temp > 0)
                        {
                            int rem = temp % 10;
                            if (rem == 2)
                            {
                                count++;
                                if (k < a)
                                {
                                    array[k] = j;
                                    k++;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            temp /= 10;
                        }
                        if (count == a)
                        {
                            int countTemp = 0;
                            for (int h = 0; h < a; h++)
                            {
                                if (h + 1 < a)
                                {
                                    if (array[h + 1] == array[h] + 1 && array[0] == 1 && array[h] > 0)
                                    {
                                        countTemp++;
                                        if (countTemp == a - 1)
                                            return i;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```